# Use lag to select previous row based on current row value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I have a table like as shown below

```
person_id  source_system   r_diff
  1              A          NULL
  1              B           0
  1              B           9
  1              A           15
  1              A           574
  1              B           0
  1              A           63
  1              A           136
  1              B           0
```

I would like to select data based on `Or operation` of 2 rules

a) Select all records where `source_system = B`

b) Select n and n-1 rows where r_diff = 0.

For example, in the above data, you can find `r_diff = 0` for row numbers `2,6,9`. So, I would like to select rows 1,2 and 5,6 and 8,9. You can see how I have chosen n and n-1 rows

I tried the below

```
select *, lag(*) from table A
where (r_diff is NULL or r_diff = 0) or source_system in ('B')
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
person_id  source_system   r_diff
  1              A          NULL
  1              B           0
  1              B           9
  1              A           574
  1              B           0
  1              A           136
  1              B           0
```

Comment: how is your data orderd? if you order them in a different way your previous row could be different than expected

Comment: It's ordered based on time. In sample dataframe there is no time info. But you can assume the order above will remain constant and am looking for a solution based on above order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question presumes an ordering in the table . . . so I have to assume that there is a column that specifies the ordering.

You can handle this using `lead()` with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(r_dif) over (partition by person_id order by <ordering column<>) as next_r_dif
      from t
     ) t
where 0 in (next_r_dif, r_dif)
```